How to prove this function is differentiabile at this point?
Consider the function $f(x, y) = \begin{cases} e^{x} & x \leq y \\ e^{y} & x > y \end{cases}$. I'm asked to prove through boundings and majorisations that/if $f$ is continuous at $(1, 1)$ and if the partial derivatives exist at that point.
Attempts
I wanted to start with what we have been taught during the course that is we have to find some upper bound in terms of a function of a distance, like
$$|f(x, y) - f(x_0, y_0)| \leq h(x,y)$$
Where $h$ is the function of the distance. The problem is that I don't know how to start because
$$|f(x, y) - f(1, 1)| = |f(x, y) - e^1|$$
Since $f(x, y) = e^x$ when $x = y$ and when $x = y = 1$ we have $e^1$. Yet I don't know what to use for $f(x, y)$.
FOr what concerns the partial derivatives, using some restriction I would say
$$f(x, 1) = \begin{cases} e^x & x \leq 1 \\ e^y & x > 1\end{cases}$$
Hence $$f'_x(x, 1) = \begin{cases} e^x & x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x > 1 \end{cases}$$
Either cases the partial derivative exist at $(1, 1)$ since $f'_x(1, 1) = e$.
Would this be correct? I would use the same argument for $f'_y$. I'm stuck on the continuity though. I don't understand how to bound...

Hint: $f(x,1)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bwuxmvtdcz

$f(x,y)=e^{\min(x,y)}$, so $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, by composition of the two continuous functions $\exp:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $\min:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. A more "pedestrian" argument is: let $M>1$. For every $x,y\le M$,
$$|f(x,y)-f(1,1)|\le\max(|e^x-e^1|,|e^y-e^1|)\le e^M\max(|x-1|,|y-1|).$$
As for $f'_x(1,1)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x-1}$, it does not exist, since
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x-1}=0\ne e=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x-1}.$$

Thank you so much, I understood. Very clear.
